# Getting rid of crazy arrows and auto complete in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm new to Visual Studio, and I'm just trying to write code as efficiently as possible. I love intellisense and some basic auto complete functions, but I keep getting these huge diagonal arrows that pop up trying to explain something to me, and assuming entire blocks of code and inserting it for me. It slows down Visual Studio, and really gets in the way of writing the code that I actually want. I've Googled this several times, and I can't figure out what it's called, much less how to disable it. Can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't sound like Visual Studio, that sounds like an addon like CodeRush. Start disabling them to see which one it is.

Edit: For what it's worth, I'm using CodeRush right now and I'm loving it (after disabling most of the auto-correct stuff). The colored bars that show code blocks is amazing when you have nested lambdas and the code analyzer is pretty good at showing undisposed objects, unreferenced variables etc.